# How do you edit individual pixels?

Tags: python

I decided to make a image editing program using only the array given to me by the `matplotlib.pyplot.imread` method,  but when I try to assign the contents of one pixel to another, it tells me that it: `can't assign to function call`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = plt.imread("GreenScreen.png")
x1 = 250
y1 = 350
x2 = 750
xCount = x2
xCount2 = xCount
xCountStart = x2
xSet = 0
for xCount in range(xCountStart, x1):
    xCount2 = (x1 + xCount) / 2
    xSet = xCount2
    for y1 in range(350, 360):
        for xCount2 in range(xSet, xCount):
            f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
            f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
            f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
            f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
        xCount2 = xSet
    y1 = 350

plt.imshow(f)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about having brackets to assign new values to f points?

Comment: `f[xCount2, y1] = f[xSet, y1]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your parentheses `()` to square brackets `[]`, which are used for indices. Something like this should work:

```
for xCount in range(xCountStart, x1):
    xCount2 = (x1 + xCount) / 2
    xSet = xCount2
    for y1 in range(350, 360):
        for xCount2 in range(xSet, xCount):
            f[xCount2, y1] = f[xSet, y1]
            f[xCount2, y1] = f[xSet, y1]
            f[xCount2, y1] = f[xSet, y1]
            f[xCount2, y1] = f[xSet, y1]
        xCount2 = xSet
    y1 = 350 
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
f(xCount2, y1) = f(xSet, y1)
```

To set a field in `f`, use `f[xCount2, y1]`. Parentheses are used to call a function, square brackets are for indexes.